# Aligning breadcrumb separators and items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align bread crumbs but I am having a bit of difficulty if the "home" icon is a different size than the rest of the text.  And I'd like to keep the HTML as is.  https://codepen.io/trajano/pen/yLydWvK

```html
  <nav class="breadcrumb">
    <a href="#" class="breadcrumb__item breadcrumb__item--home"><img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4a/Commons-logo.svg/31px-Commons-logo.svg.png" alt="Home" /></a>
    <a href="#" class="breadcrumb__item">item 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="breadcrumb__item">item 1</a>
    <span class="breadcrumb__item breadcrumb__item--current">item 1</span>
  </nav>
```

```css
@mixin for-phone-only {
  @media (max-width: 599px) {
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin for-tablet-portrait-up {
  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin for-tablet-landscape-up {
  @media (min-width: 900px) {
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin for-desktop-up {
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    @content;
  }
}
@mixin for-big-desktop-up {
  @media (min-width: 1800px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin global-width {
  margin: auto;
  @include for-tablet-landscape-up {
    width: 800px;
  }
  @include for-desktop-up {
    width: 1080px;
  }
}

@mixin padded-width {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  @include for-tablet-landscape-up {
    padding-left: calc((100% - 800px) / 2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 800px) / 2);
  }
  @include for-desktop-up {
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1080px) / 2);
    padding-right: calc((100% - 1080px) / 2);
  }
}

.breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  @include padded-width;

  &__item {
      padding-left: 1rem;
      padding-right: 1rem;

      &:not(:last-child)::after {
          content: ">";
          padding-left: 1rem;
      }
  }
}
```

I'd also like that ">" to be non-clickable if possible.  There's no need to have it ">" either, I just want a nice separator with a ">" shape, but not use an image/svg/custom icon font if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `display: flex;align-items: center;` to your `.breadcrumb__item` element.

```
.breadcrumb { 
  display: flex;
  @include padded-width;

  &__item {
      padding-left: 1rem;
      padding-right: 1rem;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: grey;
      &:not(:last-child)::after {
          content: ">";
          padding-left: 1rem;
      }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps, answers the direct question.  Though I did find a flaw in that the items are now of different heights (so their click areas are off)

Comment: I didn't get your concern well. You mean by the items are now of different heights so they are not clickable?

Comment: If you add background color to the item you'd see that the home button which is a slightly larger image is taller than the others (as expected) but the others didn't expand as well.

Comment: In that case, you just need to remove `align-items: center` from `.breadcrumb` class. I have updated my answer. Please check it out.